# How to assign a long variable to an output in the previous command in Java?

Tags: java

I started the code like this and

```
public static long lcm_of_array_elements(int[] element_array) { 
    long lcm_of_array_elements = 1; 
    ....
    if (counter == element_array.length) { 
        return lcm_of_array_elements;
```

In my driver code:

```
int[] element_array = { a, b, c, d }; 
System.out.println(lcm_of_array_elements(element_array));
```

Here, I was getting the right value but I want to assign some variable to this value to perform some operations. I tried the following:

```
long val=lcm_of_array_elements(element_array) ;
```

However this only returned the initially defined value : 1.
So I tried, this but it displayed an error:

```
long val=lcm_of_array_elements(element_array).Last.val ;
```

Could I please get a command to store the value in some variable?

Let us take values: `a=2,b=3,c=4,d=5`

```
System.out.println(lcm_of_array_elements(element_array)); 
System.out.println(lcm_of_array_elements(element_array)); 
long k=lcm_of_array_elements(element_array) ;
System.out.println(k);
```

My output is:

```
60
1
```

But I need it to be:

```
60
60
```

Here is the full code:

```
// To check if the LCM of 4 numbers is divisible by their sum
public static long lcm_of_array_elements(int[] element_array) 
    { 
        long lcm_of_array_elements = 1; 
        int divisor = 2; 
          
        while (true) { 
            int counter = 0; 
            boolean divisible = false; 
              
            for (int i = 0; i < element_array.length; i++) { 
  
                if (element_array[i] == 0) { 
                    return 0; 
                } 
                else if (element_array[i] < 0) { 
                    element_array[i] = element_array[i] * (-1); 
                } 
                if (element_array[i] == 1) { 
                    counter++; 
                } 
  
                if (element_array[i] % divisor == 0) { 
                    divisible = true; 
                    element_array[i] = element_array[i] / divisor; 
                } 
            } 
  
           
            if (divisible) { 
                lcm_of_array_elements = lcm_of_array_elements * divisor; 
            } 
            else { 
                divisor ++; 
            } 
  
            if (counter == element_array.length) { 
                return lcm_of_array_elements; 
               
            } 
        } 
    } 
      
    // Driver Code 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        Random rand = new Random() ;
       int f = 4;
        
        while(f == 4){
        int a = rand.nextInt(100) ;
        
        int b = rand.nextInt(100) ;
        
        int c = rand.nextInt(100) ;
        
        int d = rand.nextInt(100) ;
        System.out.println(a) ;
        System.out.println(b) ;
        System.out.println(c) ;
        System.out.println(d) ;
        int e = (a + b + c + d) ;
        int[] element_array = { a, b, c, d }; 
        System.out.println(e) ;
        System.out.println(lcm_of_array_elements(element_array)); 
     long k = lcm_of_array_elements(element_array) ;
     System.out.println(k) ;
       
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in) ;
       int y = sc.nextInt();
       if(y%e==0){
           System.out.println("SUCCESS");
           f = f + 1 ;
       }
       else{
           System.out.println("FAIL");
       }
       
      }
    } 
}
```

Comment: "*`long val=lcm_of_array_elements(element_array).Last.val ;`*" - What did you expect this line of code to do?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you print the result or assign it to a variable. The value should be the same. Please, create a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can check the code. We can't tell you much from just one line.

Comment: I thought that would assign the last value of lcm_of_array_elements(element_array) as i had initialised it to be 1 but it returns the LCM after a series of operations and that is what i want to save

Comment: @default locale the printed result is correct however i want to assign that printed result to some variable in order tp perform operations on it . However, the issue is when i try store it it gives me the initialised value and not the computed value printed in the previous line

Comment: Is there any command to say``` int k= last_printed_value ;``` or anything like that?

Comment: @shriram no, there isn't.

Comment: @Turing85 Do you have an understanding of what I'm trying to do or am i a bit unclear?

Comment: @shriram for me, the question, as well as the problem statement, is totally unclear. This is partially due to an missing [MRE].

Comment: @Turing 85 Thanks for the advice i shall change it immediately

Comment: @Turing85 Is it clear now?

Comment: Try to remove the assignment altogether and write `System.out.println(lcm_of_array_elements(element_array)); ` a second time. I suspect that the assignment is irrelevant and something is changing between the calls. To help you we need a complete, runnable program: include the full code of the method and array initialization.

Comment: Yes, but i need to perform some operations on the LCM and for that i have to assign it to some variable however it clearly isn't storing the right value. Thanks again for you help

Comment: No need to thank me yet :) You should post the full code. For now, just a shot in the dark. Add this line `element_array = { a, b, c, d }; ` before the assignment. I suspect that your methods changes array contents somehow

Comment: I added a scanner statement as i was desperate to store it in a variable ... so  I manually copied the printed value into another variable y. D:

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Try**

```
import java.util.Random; 
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Main
{

  public static void main (String[]args)
  {
    Random rand = new Random ();
    int f = 4;

    while (f == 4)
    {
            int a = rand.nextInt (100);
        
            int b = rand.nextInt (100);
        
            int c = rand.nextInt (100);
        
            int d = rand.nextInt (100);
              System.out.println (a);
              System.out.println (b);
              System.out.println (c);
              System.out.println (d);
            int e = (a + b + c + d);
            int[] element_array = { a, b, c, d };
            System.out.println (e);
            //System.out.println (lcm_of_array_elements (element_array));
            long k = lcm_of_array_elements (element_array);
            System.out.println ("K: "+k);
        
            Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
            int y = sc.nextInt ();
            if (y % e == 0)
            {
                System.out.println ("SUCCESS");
                f = f + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println ("FAIL");
            }

    }
    
  }

  public static long lcm_of_array_elements (int[]element_array)
  {
    long lcm_of_array_elements = 1;
    int divisor = 2;
    
    long c=1;

    while (true)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        boolean divisible = false;
    
        for (int i = 0; i < element_array.length; i++)
        {

            if (element_array[i] == 0)
              {
                return 0;
              }
            else if (element_array[i] < 0)
              {
                element_array[i] = element_array[i] * (-1);
              }
            if (element_array[i] == 1)
              {
                counter++;
              }
    
            if (element_array[i] % divisor == 0)
              {
                divisible = true;
                element_array[i] = element_array[i] / divisor;
              }
        }


        if (divisible)
          {
            c = c * divisor;
            
          }
        else
          {
            divisor++;
          }

        if (counter == element_array.length)
          {
            return c;
    
          }
          
      
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Here K has the LCM . You can use K for another purpose.

Comment: Wow thanks so much this has helped me so much. You are truly great :)